# How to prevent a function from modifying a private variable in Java?

Tags: java, android

This absolutely drives me insane.

I have a Thing class with this kind of setup:

```
public class Thing {
    // ...

    private Rect box;
    public Rect box(){ return this.box; }

    public void render(Canvas canvas, boolean selected){
        _p.setPathEffect(null);
        _p.setColor(0x00000000);
        _p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        if(this.invisible) {
            _p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            _p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
           _p.setStrokeWidth(3);
            _p.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] {10,20}, 0));
            canvas.drawRect(this.box, _p);
            return;
        }

        if(!ResourceManager.isResource(background)){

            _p.setColor(Color.parseColor(border_color));

            Log.d("Before", this.box.toString());
            canvas.drawRect(Utils.getBorder(this.box(), border_size, border_dx, border_dy), _p);
            Log.d("After", this.box.toString());


            // ...
        }
    }
```

Note the `box` has private access and a public getter function `box()`.

Here's Utils class:

```
public final class Utils {
    public static Rect getBorder(Rect rect, int size, int dx, int dy){
        rect = inflatedRect(rect, size);
        rect.offset(dx, dy);

        return rect;
    }
    public static Rect inflatedRect(Rect r, int d){
        r.set(r.left - d, r.top - d, r.right + d, r.bottom + d);
        return r;
    }
}
```

As you might have noticed I'm using Android's Canvas, so there must be minimum allocations in render functions.

However, here's what `Log` is giving out:
[image]

Yes, the private `box` is changing even though it's passed from a getter. This results in the element's Rect rapidly increasing its size every render() call.

What can be a proper solution for this?

**EDIT 1:** This issue is totally coming from my `Utils.getBorder` function. Rectangle does not freak out if `border_size` is 0 or the line with this function is commented out. `canvas.drawRect(Utils.getBorder(this.box(), border_size, border_dx, border_dy), _p);` is its only occurence in code, and it's not used anywhere else in the project.

Comment: This is working entirely as expected.  Want to create a `Rect` with different properties?  You'll need to allocate one.  You might be able to allocate _just_ one, period, that you then reuse -- but you'll need two `Rect` objects.

Comment: the moment you let your getter pass the original Rect Object, others can edit that same object since it is not copied, but rather passed by reference. To dodge that you could create another Rect object and copy all information to this one, so they look the same, but if it gets changed somehow, the original is still in tact

Comment: Above comments are spot on, you can use the `Rect` copy constructor to make things easy https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#Rect(android.graphics.Rect)

Comment: @Japu_D_Cret nothing in Java is passed by reference. Objects are not passed to methods by reference, pointers are passed by value. Assignments to a method parameter inside the method are not visible to the method's caller, proving that the parameter was passed by value.

Comment: @LewBloch you are correct that Java never returns by reference and only by value, but by passing the value of the pointed to the object it is in layman's terms passing by reference - also if you pass an object in Java it can definitely altered so the method caller will see it, here is an example: `void Arrays.Sort(Object[])`. It modifies the passed value and does not return anything, since the result is the passed parameter itself(for reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[]) )

Comment: No, passing a pointer by value is not the same as pass-by-reference. Pass-by-value and pass-by-reference are simply not "layman's terms". They are terms of art with objective definitions. It isn't a matter of opinion or vague hand-waving. Java does not pass parameters by reference. That is a fact.

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077424/learn-java/does-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value.html http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm http://jonskeet.uk/java/passing.html and last but not least, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html "Reference data type parameters, such as objects, are also passed into methods by value." Straight from the horse's mouth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is as follows...

```
public final class Utils {
    public static Rect getBorder(final Rect rect, int size, int dx, int dy){
        Rect inflatedRect = inflatedRect(rect, size);
        inflatedRect.offset(dx, dy);

        return inflatedRect;
    }

    public static Rect inflatedRect(final Rect r, int d){
        return new Rect(r.left - d, r.top - d, r.right + d, r.bottom + d);
    }
}
```

Comment: `final` does not guarantee that method arguments are immutable, and it matters not a hoot to the caller if the parameter is `final`, since it will not see any changes to the parameter due to arguments being passed by value. A `final` variable does not necessarily point to an immutable object.